# populate objectlistview using datatable list

Tags: c#, objectlistview

im currently work with objectlistview and get trouble to populate data from database with list , here my code

```
    static internal List<Birthday> GetBirthdays()
    {
        if (Birthday.Alldata.Count == 0)
            Birthday.Alldata = Birthday.InitializeData();
        return Birthday.Alldata;
    }
    static private List<Birthday> Alldata = new List<Birthday>();

    static private List<Birthday> InitializeData()
    {
        koneksi con = new koneksi();
        var qcmd = "Select nm, sex, replace(hp, ' ', '') as Hp, datediff(YEAR, left(tgllhr, 4), '2016') as Umur, alamat  " +
                    "from mcif " +
                    "where right(tgllhr, 4) = 20160615";


        con.SqlQuery(qcmd);

        List<Birthday> Birthdaylist = new List<Birthday>();
        using (DataTable dt = con.QueryEx())
        {
            Birthdaylist = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

                       select new Birthday()
                       {
                           nama = Convert.ToString(dr["nm"]),
                           sex = Convert.ToString(dr["sex"]),
                           hp = Convert.ToString(dr["hp"]),
                           umur = Convert.ToInt32(dr["umur"]),
                           alamat = Convert.ToString(dr["alamat"])
                       }).ToList();

        }
```

and this is my connection

```
public class koneksi
{


    private SqlConnection _con;
    private SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter _da;
    private DataTable _dt;


    public koneksi(string connectionstring=null)
    {
        var MyIni = new IniFile("setting.ini");
        string database = MyIni.Read("SET1", "Database");
        string userdb = MyIni.Read("SET2", "Database");
        string passdb = MyIni.Read("SET3", "Database");
        string locdb = MyIni.Read("SET4", "Database");

        _con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring??@"Data Source=" + locdb + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + "; User ID=" + userdb + ";password=" + passdb + "");
        _con.Open();

    }

    public void SqlQuery(string queryText)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, _con);
    }

    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        _dt = new DataTable();
        _da.Fill(_dt);
        return _dt;
    }


}
```

this code in form :

```
private void InitializeDataOlv()
    {


        this.flv.SetObjects(Birthday.GetBirthdays());
    }
```

I have try several example from [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/) but my olv still empty, actually i still beginner using model list

Comment: I do not see any code related to the ObjectListView component.

Comment: i just using this call on olv

private void InitializeDataOlv()
        {
            this.flv.SetObjects(Birthday.GetBirthdays());
        }

Comment: You have to setup/initialize the OLV accordingly. Add the required columns in the editor and tell the OLV columns where they should take the data from. You either have to set the "AspectName" properties to the respective property names of the Birthday OR use the "AspectGetter" callbacks.

Comment: actually i have had set the aspectName ,, the olv wil display the data if I make the List manually, like olv example,

Comment: Then its hard to help here. Are you sure your List contains data after calling InitializeData()? If its works "manually" the problem isn't the OLV.